# fflush(FILE *stream) not working?

Tags: c, file-handling, fflush

```
while(1)
{
    ch=fgetc(ft);
    if(ch==EOF)
    {
        break;
    }
    if(ch=='u')
    {
        fputc('b',ft);
        fflush(ft);
    }
}
```

I tried to replace character after `u` with `b` in a file pointed by `*ft`.

This code runs fine but when I open the file it seemed to be unedited.

The above code works fine with `fseeks(ft,0,SEEK_CUR)`.

Why it is not working with `fflush(ft)`.

Comment: Why would you expect it to work?

Comment: BTW your classmate already submitted the exact same question...

Comment: @R.. : I got the problem...It is between fgetc() and fputc(). I have to put fseek() between them

Comment: @R.. : why fflush does not flush input streams

Comment: What would "flushing" an input stream mean? Even if such an operation existed, it wouldn't eliminate the requirement to perform a successful seek between reading and writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fflush only flushes output stream. Hence you need to put `fseek(ft,0,SEEK_CUR)` above your `fputs(ft)`